# Disable Grunt task run only in production environment sails js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I want to disable grunt task runner in production mode to fasten up server deployment? how to disable it placing it in .sailrc file will disable for all environment.

Comment: Have you try to edit tasks/register/prod.js and remove the tasks you don't want ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply edit the .`sailsrc` file and set the `grunt` property to `false`

```
{
    "hooks": {
        "grunt": false
    }
}
```

See [Disabling Grunt](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/disabling-grunt) o sails website

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into `tasks/register/prod.js` you can find following content:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    'compileAssets',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    'sails-linker:prodJs',
    'sails-linker:prodStyles',
    'sails-linker:devTpl',
    'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
    'sails-linker:prodStylesJade',
    'sails-linker:devTplJade'
  ]);
};
```

All tasks that calling from that file is located under `config` folder.

So you can just comment our or remove tasks that you don't need. Just edit `tasks/register/prod.js` file.

For example, I don't have Jade template engine. I can just remove this task from `grunt.registerTask()` by removing `sails-linker:prodJsJade` and `sails-linker:prodStylesJade`.

I hope you got it :)

BTW, **DON'T REMOVE** `compileAssets` task because it copies all the assets files to public folder exposed by express static.